# Type mismatch error in multi threading

Tags: c#, multithreading

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
public class pgm
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Thread newThread = new Thread(pgm.work1);
        newThread.Start(20);
        pgm p = new pgm();
        newThread = new Thread(p.work2);
        newThread.Start("Instance");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public static void work1(object data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Static Thread Procedure : Data ='{0}'",data);
    }
    public void work2(object data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Instance Thread Procedure : Data ='{0}'", data);
    }
}
```

When I write arguments of work1 and work2 methods as "int data" and "string data", it is throwing type mismatch error. Why?

Answer (score 0):

The constructor for `Thread` that you're using has this signature:

```
public Thread(ParameterizedThreadStart start)
```

With `ParameterizedThreadStart` being a delegate with this signature:

```
public delegate void ParameterizedThreadStart(object obj)
```

So when you try to start the methods `void work1(object data)` and `void work2(object data)` they match this signature so it works fine.

But when you change them to be `void work1(int data)` and `void work2(string data)` then they don't match and the compiler let's you know that.

If you could do what you're trying then it'd lead to the possibility of doing this:

```
Thread newThread = new Thread(pgm.work1);
newThread.Start("Some String"); //but `pgm.work1` takes an `int`!
```

And this would lead to a runt-time exception. Part of the compiler's job is to prevent you making mistake like this. Hence it is a compile-time error.